Converting/copying an SQL Server database with SBCS Latin1 collation to UTF-8 collation
In SQL Server 2022, we have a database with collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_SC, using CHAR/VARCHAR columns (not NCHAR/NVARCHAR).
We want to move to UTF-8.
I created a new DB with collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_SC_UTF8, and tried SQL Server Management Studio tool Tasks => Export data... (Using SQL Native Client 11 as client tool)
Seems that it is not supported. The export report shows this error:
- Copying to [dbo].[tab1] (Error)
    Messages
    * Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
    An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
    An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid data for UTF8-encoded characters".
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I will try SQL Server Management Studio 20.2

Have you tried using something other than SQL Native Client 11? SNAC 11 was last shipped with SQL Server 2012, was deprecated back then, and had no new feature development carried out on it before Microsoft stopped distributing it as of SQL Server 2022. UTF-8 collations were introduced with SQL Server 2019 so it's unsurprising that SNAC 11 is having problems with that content.

The error complains that the bytes are invalid for UTF8. You can't just get Latin1 bytes and store them in a field with UTF8 collation, you have to convert them. Which is as expensive as converting them to nvarchar

Why UTF8 instead of nvarchar? You don't conserve space unless all text is in the US-ASCII range. Anything above 0x7F requires 2 bytes. If you really want to save space and IO, use compression. You don't get any performance gains either, and in some cases, depending on the SQL Server version, you can get worse performance. Check SQL Server 2019 UTF-8 Support Benefits where the answer is ... there aren't many.

Yep choosing Native Client 11 was not the best choice I agree.
BTW we are using Microsoft ODBC for SQL Server in our solution.
Here it's just about finding the right tool to do the DB collation conversion.
I have now installed the latest SQL Server Management Studio version 20.2, and tried with the Microsoft OLE DB for SQL Server client as data source.
The export to the UTF-8 database succeeded: characters where converted properly to UTF-8.
However, the Primary Key and Unique constraints where lost!!

Why UTF-8? Because to us, it's THE standard today.
We know about UTF-8 pros and cons.
Most data is ASCII-7 (one byte). But we can get data from Restful requests (thus UTF-8)
In our context, we want to use UTF-8 in the whole software chain and avoid conversions between UTF-8 Restful requests and the DB using potentially UTF-16 in NCHAR/NVARCHAR columns.

Here is our config / software chain (running on Linux or Windows):
RESTful server (Written in C/C++)
<=>
Microsoft ODBC 18 for SQL Server
<=>
SQL Server 2022

i think it's better to script the database and tables and then populate them, or use bacpac/dacpac

Using Export Data-Tier Application:
I have tested, but could not find any option to control/change the collation.

Have you tried a straight INSERT NewDb.dbo.NewTable (ColumnsHere) SELECT ColumnsHere FROM OldDb.dbo.NewTable

@Charlieface - if you have a large database with hundreds of tables you don't want to write INSERT .. SELECT statements for each of them
MS should provide a straight forward tool to do such conversion.
